# User Current Location - Mapkit iOS Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, core-location

I am trying to find User's current location using Location Manager. Below is my code in viewdidload

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

locationManager.delegate = self;

//locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;

locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER)
{
    [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

    [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

and in didUpdateLocations

```
self.userLocation = locations.lastObject;

if (userLocation != nil)
{
    NSLog(@"sdsd %f %f", userLocation.coordinate.longitude, userLocation.coordinate.latitude);

[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Am getting confirmation dialog and users location as set in simulation but not real time location even in device. I configured all settings in both device as well as xcode but still getting default location only.

Please let me know what should I do to get my realtime location and not simulation location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simulator does not receive your current location from the operating system. To debug you can select `Debug->Location->City Bicycle Ride` in the simulator. This will simulate a bike ride around the block.

On the device it can take a while to get your current location if you are indoors. Turning on bluetooth and WIFI help iOS get a location faster.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I went with Custom location option. But I think its better to check with devices for scenarios like these..

Answer (score 0):

Open your `xCode` go to `Product-> Scheme-> Edit` Scheme and then here inside `Run` select `Core location` and check the `Allow location simulation`. May be it will work.

Comment: Thanx for your reply.. I have did this already and this is my problem. Whatever I set as default location in that dropdown becomes my location and not my actual location.

Comment: Have you try to change it to None?

Comment: I tried that and if its none then it returns coordinates which I previously used. I mean if I set default to London then it returns London coordinates and after that If I set it to none then also it returns London coordinates (which I previously used)..